# Viewport on mobiles not defaulting to show full site

Tags: mobile, viewport

i have a fixed width site, and the client has requested that when it is viewed on a mobile, it should show the whole site by default (ie zoomed out).

In my head i have the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Which is the code that came with the wordpress template im currently using.
Ive looked around various answers on here, and tried various different combinations, however, whichever i use, the site always loads on a mobile  with the screen zoomed right in to the top corner (have tested a couple on phones, and a couple with responsinator).

I know im probably being really daft here and missing something really obvious, but if anyone could help itd be hugely appreciated!

If anyone would like to take a look at the site directly, its [EdoMidas.com](http://www.edomidas.com)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Replace 1140 with the width of your website.